# How to get FAB to float over WebView in Xamarin XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, floating-action-button

I'm trying to setup a XAML form definition which shows a WebView but which has a Floating Action Button over the bottom right.

If I use an AbsoluteLayout, the FAB appears correctly over the WebView.  However, due to the Height/WidthRequest of the Webview, it is displayed at full size - the text disappears off the right side and doesn't wrap, so the page doesn't scroll.

```
<ContentPage ...snip... Title="Document">
    <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
        <WebView x:Name="webViewDocument" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" />
        <Label Text="{Binding UpdatedWhen, StringFormat='Last Updated: {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}'}" 
                               VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" />
        <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="fab" 
                                Source="{markupExtensions:PlatformImage SourceImage='IconFAB'}"
                                Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.95,0.975,-1,-1"
                                Margin="10" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

If I use a StackLayout, the WebView sizes and scrolls correctly, however the FAB occupies a full width strip at the bottom of the screen and the text does not appear behind it - the WebView stops above it.

I've spent the last hour and a half trying every combination of nested Layout I can think of to solve this and just can't get it right - can some kind layout genius out there please tell me how I can solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a  `Grid` and do not indicate rows or columns.

Something like this:

```
<Grid Padding="5,5,5,5"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <WebView x:Name="webViewDocument"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    <Label Text="{Binding UpdatedWhen, StringFormat='Last Updated: {0:dd MMM yyyy HH:mm}'}"
           VerticalOptions="End"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
           FontSize="Small" />
    <customControls:ImageButton x:Name="fab"
                                Source="{markupExtensions:PlatformImage SourceImage='IconFAB'}"
                                Command="{Binding AddCommand}"
                                VerticalOptions="End"
                                HorizontalOptions="End"
                                Margin="10" />
</Grid>
```

This should work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Aaaurgh, so close I can taste it!  The text is correctly wrapped and the FAB renders correctly over the webview... but the webview text doesn't scroll.  Still it's so much closer than I've got before...

Comment: @Mike it does not scroll since made a mistake when typing the solution. I just updated my answer and should work now. In resume, you use the Vertical and Horizontal options but _not_ the height/width

Comment: I appreciate your help, mate.  It still won't scroll.  Strangely enough I can see the scroll bar appear briefly at the top right when the form appears which suggests it knows the length of the doc is greater than the screen, it just won't respond to swipes up and down.  To clarify - this is in a Shared project of a Android/iOS solution and I'm trying to get it working in Android.

Comment: Scrub that, it was the label that was blocking it because I'd missed the Horizontal and Vertical options.  You're a "kind layout genius" in my books mate.